# SourceTree password after opening Bitbucket account with gmail

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

I use my gmail account to create and log into my bitbucket account (similar to how I do with stack overflow). Now I am trying to access my repository through SourceTree. when it asks for password, I am not sure what to enter. When I enter my google credentials it fails.

Answer (score 30):

When installing *SourceTree*, the install wizard prompts you for your **username** and **password** for *BitBucket*.  **This has nothing to do with your ssh keys** as that comes later.

**Username** - please refer to **Bitbucket.Manage Account.Change Username** to find the correct username.  This is not the same as your Google account or if the value matches then that is by coincidence.

**Password** - this is the password when you created your account.  If you have forgotten then refer to **Bitbucket.Manage Account.Change Password**.   You should then enter that in the install wizard.

Finally, the wizard will ask about ssh keys and it is at this point to need to provide your ssh password, assuming you have one.

Enjoy

Comment: This was driving me **batty**. Thank you so much Micky Duncan. Your answer worked for me. Future Googlers, also note that when walking through the SoureTree setup wizard, there is a dialog that asks for **user name**, which does not have to be your email address.

Comment: Yeah, I made a new account, which includes setting a password, but had this error. I just "changed" the password to the same thing, and *poof*, working.

Comment: How do I change the password now? Bitbucket now asks me for old password which I don't know.

Comment: As an addition to this, if you _deleted_ your old password in the GUI instead of _editing_ it or starting the _wizard_, you will have to manually delete it again for it to even ask the password _C:\users\username\AppData\Local\Atlassian\Bitbucket\passwd_

Comment: Try going back one screen and selecting Atlassian account, this gives you the option to sign in with google, worked first try for me.

Answer (score 4):

You have to create a new app password for Sourcetree in the bitbucket settings

Answer (score -3):

I had a similar issue.

Using only lowercase for the username solved it for me